# Google App Engine very slow response time in file upload

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, dropzone.js

I have a Django app running on GAE(Google App Engine) standard environment. I am uploading videos via my app to google cloud buckets (utilising dropzone on front end). The size of my videos are large so I am sending my file in chunks to GAE and then recreate and upload to GCS. It is working fine.

My issues is the request to upload the chunks are taking a long time 
(15s for uploading a chunk of 1MB, I removed the processing of the chunk and still taking 15s)

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def upload_chunks(request):
    try:
        file = request.FILES['file']            
        # upload_utils.upload_image_file(file); //Commented it out
        return JsonResponse({"status": True})
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponseServerError(str(e))
```

Every Chunk Upload takes 15 sec and all of the time is spent in TTFB

[image: Every Chunk Upload takes 15 sec]

[image]

Also when increase my chunk size to let's say 8 MB the request get cancelled as it takes more than 30 sec.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

So the PHP docs offer `CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl()`:

> User upload of files directly to Google Cloud Storage is faster and more cost-effective than writing to Google Cloud Storage from your App Engine app, because this consumes instance hours and incurs cost. Moreover, the file write does not occur within a request to the application. Therefore it is exempt from the 60 second limit that would otherwise apply and allows uploads of very large files.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload#createuploadurl_options

But the python cloudstorage docs dont seem to have a reciprocal section

However, the old blobstore docs have a similarly name `create_upload_url()` where you specify `gs_bucket_name`:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.create_upload_url

So maybe that will do it

More info on the blobstore docs:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers#BlobstoreUploadHandler

Answer (score 0):

Best way to upload big files to the Google Cloud is to [do it directly to the Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects). It is possible to accomplish this task using two distinct methods:

1. Uploading parallel chunks (up to 32) and then [composing them to one object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects#_Uploads). Using this approach, do not forget to delete temporary chunks.
2. Using resumable uploads, that will be [automatically resumed when interrupted](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload).
   Here is [example code do upload video using javascript](https://github.com/googleapis/gcs-resumable-upload):

---